# Count Odd Numbers in an Interval Range. Leetcode problem №1523. Python

Tags: python, count, numbers

I tried to solve this problem from leetcode and I came up with the following code but the testcase where low = 3 and high = 7 gives 2 as an output and 3 is expected by leetcode. I will be grateful if you explain what is wrong and how it should be done.

```
class Solution:
   def countOdds(self, low: int, high: int) -> int:
      count = 0
      for i in range(low, high):
         if i % 2 != 0:
            count += 1
      return count
```

Comment: That is not acceptable formatting for stack overflow question. Python code requires proper indentation to be understandable. Also, merely stating "it fails" is not a useful description of the problem. Instead, explain precisely what is wrong and provide sample inputs that illustrate the failure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`range(low, high)` will result in a range of (low, low+1, low+2, ..., high -1). Meaning that in your case high will not be considered.

If high should also be considered use:

```
range(low, high + 1)
```

Comment: Tried it. Case with low = 800445804 and high = 979430543 fails due to Time Limit Exceeded. Means I should somehow optimize the code?

Comment: @childoflogos Yes, you need to optimize. Note that you can solve it with simple math - no loop required. Something like `count = (high - low) / 2` should get you started.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Solution:
    def countOdds(self, low: int, high: int) -> int:
        # lst = [ num for num  in range(low , high+1) if num%2!=0]
        # return len(lst)
        # brut force doesnt gona work 
        # it works but it nearly take 15 seconds
        # very high
       

    #case 1 => both odd
    if low%2!=0 and high%2!=0:
        return int((high - low)/2) + 1
    
    #case 2 => both even

    if low%2==0 and high%2==0:
        #division is always float
        return int((high -low)/2)
    
    # case 3 => either one of them is even and other is odd
    if (low%2==0 and high%2!=0 ) or (low%2!=0 and high%2==0):
        return int((high - low)/2)+1
```